Lower bounding a product of many terms
I have been trying to find a lower bound for a probability which is given by the expression
$$
P_0 \geq \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} (x_i)^{2^{N-i}},  
$$
where $\forall i, \;\; \Delta<x_i \leq 1 $ with $\Delta >0$ . But we could actually impose other conditions on $\Delta$ if necessary.
In particular, $x_i$ can be written as:
$$
x_i = \frac{2^{p-i} \gamma(i) -7c}{2^{p-i} \gamma(i) -2c}
$$
with the condition that
$$
\gamma(i) > 2\frac{c}{2^{p-i}},
$$

I tried various approaches, like logarithm transformation, to write it in terms of a sum and see if I could bound it with triangle inequality or Jensen inequality but I could not get anything meaningful.
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much!

From numerics I can see that the quantity is decreasing polynomially fast when N increases. So, ideally, I would like to find a polynomial expression which will be some function of x_i

It seems that $x_i$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$, in which case there is no nontrivial lower bound (for even a single term, let alone the whole product).

Thanks! I actualy found there is a mistake in what I wrote. Fixing it now.

One might as well strengthen the condition to $\gamma(i) > {c (7-2 \Delta) }/(1-\Delta)2^{p-i}$, since that is the region where $x_i>\Delta$. And it seems that each $x_i$ can be made as small as $\Delta$, so that the whole expression can be as small as $\Delta^{4^{2^n-1}}$.

Hello both and thanks. This sounds like a good idea. I will try it out when I get a moment to work on it and post the attempt. Thanks again. :)
